# Notify() does not work even though argument already met

Tags: java, concurrency

My program runs and it waits normally, but it does not reach to notify.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> beltQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> sterilizeQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> sterilize1Q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> fillingQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> sealingQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> labellingQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> packagingQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> loadingQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> deliveryQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> customer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        Belt b = new Belt(beltQ, boxingQ);
        Sterilize s = new Sterilize(beltQ, sterilizeQ, boxingQ);
        Sterilize1 s1 = new Sterilize1(sterilizeQ, sterilize1Q, boxingQ);
        Filling f = new Filling(sterilize1Q, fillingQ, boxingQ);
        Sealing seal = new Sealing(fillingQ, sealingQ, boxingQ);
        Labelling l = new Labelling(sealingQ, labellingQ, boxingQ);
        Packaging p = new Packaging(labellingQ, packagingQ, boxingQ);
        Boxing box = new Boxing(packagingQ, boxingQ);
        b.start();
        s.start();
        s1.start();
        f.start();
        seal.start();
        l.start();
        p.start();
        box.start();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            ForkliftTruck ft = new ForkliftTruck(boxingQ, loadingQ, i);
            ft.start();
        }
        LoadingArea la = new LoadingArea(2);
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            DeliveryVan dv = new DeliveryVan(la, i, loadingQ, deliveryQ, customer);
            dv.start();
        }
    }

class Packaging extends Thread {

    LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> labellingQ;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> packagingQ;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ;

    public Packaging(LinkedBlockingQueue<Can> labellingQ, LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> packagingQ, LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ) {
        this.labellingQ = labellingQ;
        this.packagingQ = packagingQ;
        this.boxingQ = boxingQ;
    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        int boxNo = 1;
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (boxingQLock) {
                while (boxingQ.size() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Production is paused");
                    boxingQLock.wait();
                }
            }
                if (labellingQ.size() == 6) {
                    System.out.println("Packaging cans into box ");
                    Can can1 = labellingQ.take();
                    Can can2 = labellingQ.take();
                    Can can3 = labellingQ.take();
                    Can can4 = labellingQ.take();
                    Can can5 = labellingQ.take();
                    Can can6 = labellingQ.take();
                    System.out.println("Cans have been shrink wrapped");
                    Box bx = new Box(can1, can2, can3, can4, can5, can6, boxNo);
                    packagingQ.put(bx);
                    System.out.println("Cans " + can1.CanNo + " " + can2.CanNo + " " + can3.CanNo + " " + can4.CanNo + " " + can5.CanNo + " " + can6.CanNo + " has been packed into packet " + bx.BoxNo);
                    boxNo++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}


class Boxing extends Thread {

LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> packagingQ;
LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ;

public Boxing(LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> packagingQ, LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ) {
    this.packagingQ = packagingQ;
    this.boxingQ = boxingQ;
}

synchronized public void run() {
    int bigboxNo = 1;

    while (true) {
        try {
            LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> packet = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Box>(2);
            if (boxingQ.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println("No space!! Waiting for boxed to be taken!");
                System.out.println("No space!! Waiting for boxed to be taken!");
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                Box b1 = packagingQ.take();
                System.out.println("Loading packets into boxes");
                packet.put(b1);
            }
            Bigbox big = new Bigbox(packet, bigboxNo);
            bigboxNo++;
            System.out.println("Packets  have been loaded into box " + big.BigboxNo);
            boxingQ.put(big);
            System.out.println("BoxingQ size: " + boxingQ.size());
            System.out.println("Box has been stored into loading area");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
}
class ForkliftTruck extends Thread {

    LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ;
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> loadingQ;
    int forkno;

    public ForkliftTruck(LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> boxingQ, LinkedBlockingQueue<Bigbox> loadingQ, int forkno) {
        this.boxingQ = boxingQ;
        this.loadingQ = loadingQ;
        this.forkno = forkno;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                 synchronized (boxingQLock) {
                Bigbox bb = boxingQ.take();
                boxingQLock.notifyAll();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println("Production is resumed");
                System.out.println("Forklift " + forkno + " has picked box " + bb.BigboxNo);
                Random rand = new Random();
                int fdefect = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
                if (fdefect == 2) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Forklift " + forkno + " has broken down......waiting for repair");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Forklift " + forkno + " is repaired......successfully placed box " + bb.BigboxNo + " in the loading bay");
                    loadingQ.put(bb);
                    System.out.println("LoadingQ size: " + loadingQ.size());
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Forklift " + forkno + " is in good condition");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println("Forklift " + forkno + " has successfully placed box " + bb.BigboxNo + " in the loading bay");
                    loadingQ.put(bb);
                    System.out.println("LoadingQ size: " + loadingQ.size());
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the output, once the `boxingQ.size` reaches 1, it pauses, but once it takes out from the queue and reduces to 0, the `notify()`function doesnt seem to work

Here is my output

```
Loading packets into boxes
Cans 8 9 11 12 14 16 has been packed into packet 2 //2 packets go into one box
Packets  have been loaded into box 1
BoxingQ size: 1
Box has been stored into loading area
Production is paused
Forklift 1 has picked box 1
```

As you can see, as the forklift has picked the box, the boxingQ currently have 0 items in the queue. But the production does not resume

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry, I have revised

Comment: When you call `wait` in Packaging thread, there is no other thread running that calls `notify` to release that waiting thread.

Comment: @BurakSerdar how do I notify the thread that has been waiting?

Comment: @JagdeeshSandhu, You don't notify a thread, you notify the _object_ on which the thread is waiting.  A call to `o.notifyAll()` will wake every thread that is blocked in `o.wait()` for the same object, `o`. A call to `o.notify()` will wake just one of them. Notice that, if no thread is waiting, then `o.notify()` and `o.notifyAll()` do not do anything at all.

Comment: @SolomonSlow but if i do that, i get the argument that says invoking object wai toutside a synchronized context despite me having a synchronized context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `notify` will release a thread waiting on the object you called `notify`. That is, if a thread calls `obj.wait()`, another thread has to call `obj.notify()` to wake up the waiting thread.

In your case, it looks like you need to wait until boxingQ satisfies a certain condition. You can use object for this:

```
static final Object boxingQLock=new Object();

synchronized (boxingQLock) {
   while ( boxingQ does not satisfy the condition) {
      boxingQLock.wait(); 
   } 
   // when you come here, boxingQ satisfies the condition, and you are
   // holding a lock on it
}
```

And, in another thread that modifies boxingQ:

```
synchronized (boxingQLock) {
   // Modify boxingQ
   // Notify a thread
   boxingQLock.notify(); //or notifyAll()
}
```

All the discussion about the wait/notify aside: you are using a `BlockingQueue`. That means, you can simply call `take` and wait until someone puts something into the queue and not worry about synchronization/wait/notify at all. However, code like the following is inherently racy:

```
if (labellingQ.size() == 6) {
  System.out.println("Packaging cans into box ");
  Can can1 = labellingQ.take();
  Can can2 = labellingQ.take();
  ...
```

because without explicit locking, the queue size may change after you read it. There is no guarantee that after you read the length other threads won't do the same and try to take elements from it. One way to do this is to take 6 times, and let the queue take care of waiting if there isn't enough. Or, use a lock for labellingQ, check if there are enough items and grab all 6 in a  synchronized block, so when you know there are enough items no other thread can get them before you.

Comment: if i do that way, the synchronized(boxingQ) highlights on boxingQ it says synchronization on non final field

Comment: You can use a final object for the same purpose. I modified the code,

Comment: The object has to be static as well, so same instance is shared among threads.

Comment: do i define the static final lock in my main method or the threads which i wanna pause and resume?

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as all threads using it can see it, because it is static. You can define it as a private variable where you define the queues. You'd need one such lock variable for each queue where you'd need something similar.

Comment: it still says illegal start of expression

Comment: You can declare it as a static final variable in Boxing thread.

Comment: when i notify my threads, do i notifyAll or use notify because I'm using the wait for more than on thread?

Comment: If multiple threads are waiting on a condition and when the condition happens several of them can resume, use notifyAll(). If only one of them can resume, use notify().

Comment: I have revised my code, but still not all of my threads are resuming, is there any error in my code

Comment: There is at least one instance of boxingQ.put in boxing thread that doesn't notify anybody. It is up to you to figure out the rest.